# serious problem inserting html into database using textarea

Tags: jquery, html, insert, textarea, sql-insert

To start with l'm trying to build an admin n panel for a website where the administrator can easily add html links to content with the click of a button. The tech nique I'm trying to use is letting the user type in a text which I call link text and also another text which I call linkto. Then when the user clicks the add link button a jQuery code creates a new '' element , inserts the link to text as the href and the link text as the text between the opening and closing tags. My problem is that when  this is inserted into the database, it simply ignores the HTML tags inserting onle the link text. I'll call myself a newbie. I really need help fast. Anyone ?

Here's the code for the HTML form :

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" name="head" placeholder="add heading"><br>
    <textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea><br>
    <input type="text" name="link" id="linkto"><br>
    <input type="text" name="link" id="linktext"><br>
    <span id="addlink">add link</span><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here's the jQuery code:

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addlink").click(function() {
        var linkTo = $("#linkto").val();
        var linkText = $("#linktext").val();
        $("#content").append("<a href="+linkTo+">"+linkText+"</a>");
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the code for the PHP processing:

```
if (isset($_POST['head'])) {

    $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die();

    mysqli_select_db($conn,'temp');

    $heading = $_POST['head'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO posts VALUES(?,?)";

    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$heading,$content);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: 1) I'm real unsure about appending some HTML to a `textarea`... 2) You have a double quotes issue anyway in that appending. 3) There is no `name` to the textarea, so it's content is not submitted at all.

Comment: How do I correct the double quotes problem please

Comment: Is there any other way to do what I want to do without textarea